# Перезаписать url страницы

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть 2 таксономии `product_brand` - бренды и `product_cat` - категории.
Для того чтобы показать товары категории определенного бренда используется ссылки вида:

`/product_brand/brand_name/?attributes[product_cat]=product_cat_id`

Как преобразовать его в:

`/product_brand/brand_name/product_cat_name`

Я так понял мне нужно использовать функцию `add_rewrite_rule()`, но не могу понять как заставить ее работать.

```
  function custom_rewrite_rules() {
        add_rewrite_rule('^product_brand/(.*)/(.*)?', 'index.php?&attributes[product_cat]=$matches[1]', 'top');
  }
    add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rules');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогло следующее:

```
function custom_rewrite_rules() {

        // порядок имеет значение
        // для ссылок типа: product_brand/brand_name/page
        add_rewrite_rule( '^product_brand/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]{1,})/?', 'index.php?product_brand=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]', 'top' );
        // для ссылок типа: product_brand/brand_name/category_name/page
        add_rewrite_rule( '^product_brand/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]{1,})/?', 'index.php?product_brand=$matches[1]&product_cat=$matches[2]&page=$matches[3]', 'top' );
        // для ссылок типа: product_brand/brand_name/category_name
        add_rewrite_rule('^product_brand/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?', 'index.php?product_brand=$matches[1]&product_cat=$matches[2]', 'top');

        add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $vars ){
            $vars[] = 'product_brand';
            $vars[] = 'product_cat';
            return $vars;
        } );
    }
    add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rules');
```

Для того чтобы заставить WP переключать страницы, дополнительно пришлось добавить это

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function() {
 $page = get_query_var('page');
 $query->set( 'paged', $page );
 return $query;
} );
```